# wilcoxonPairedR error - Testing works for one dataset but not for the other

Tags: r, statistics, pairwise.wilcox.test

I just wasted a whole day searching for a solution for my problem.

So briefly, I have 2 datasets with 2 samples each from a wilcox_test. Now, I wanted to test for effect size. For the first dataset I receive an effect size "r", for the other I receive a error message:

```
library(rcompanion)
wilcoxonPairedR(x = sport_1_4$value, g = sport_1_4$variable)

Fehler in wilcoxonZ(x = x[as.numeric(g) == 1], y = x[as.numeric(g) == 2],  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

I did exactly the same, but it won't work.

EDIT: I have the same amount of obs for both variables.

```
> table(sport_1_4$variable)

sport_t1 sport_t2 sport_t3 sport_t4 
      38        0        0       38
```

dataset1 - testing t1 and t2

```
> head(sport_1_2)
  ID variable value
1  1 sport_t1     2
2  2 sport_t1     4
3  3 sport_t1     4
4  4 sport_t1     2
5  5 sport_t1     3
6  6 sport_t1     2
```

dataset2 - testing t1 and t4

```
> head(sport_1_4)
  ID variable value
1  1 sport_t1     2
2  2 sport_t1     4
3  3 sport_t1     4
4  4 sport_t1     2
5  5 sport_t1     3
6  6 sport_t1     2
```

Comment: The wilcoxian paired test you are trying to run requires paired data - there must be the same number of observations in group 1 and in group 2. This error message is telling you that group 1 has a different number of observations (length) than group 2.

Comment: run `table(sport_1_2$variable)` to see how many observations are in each group.

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade I ran the table code, please check my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by copying the dataset into a new excel sheet, and importing it into Rstudio. Now it works... I didn't change anything at all. Weird.